# I got [prefix] [suffix] [infix] from washing the [whole]

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

> I got [prefix] [suffix] [infix] from washing the [whole].
>
> *P.S. I [infix] the [whole].*

The note above, when the gaps are filled, will be a grammatical and reasonable note.
What is the note?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not stated in the question as it stands, but if it is legitimate to assume that the two 'infixes' mentioned in the riddle *need not be the same*, then here is one solution:

> I got **WATER... ...ON ...ME...** from washing the **WATERMELON**.
>
>  *P.S. I **...ATE...** the **WATERMELON**.*
>
>  Here, **WATER** is the prefix, **ATE** and **ME** are both separate infixes within the word, and **ON** is the suffix.

Of course, nowhere in the rules does it say that *every letter within the whole word is used in this puzzle*. This is pertinent here since:

> Nowhere in the 'fixes' is the letter **L** clued. One (slightly tongue-in-cheek) way to overcome this is to assume that while washing said watermelon our friend **MEL** got a little too close to the tap and ended up being sprayed, meaning that:
>
>  I got **WATER... ...ON ...MEL(!)...** from washing the **WATERMELON**!